# Does addEventListener cause memory leaks?

Tags: javascript, events, memory, memory-leaks, dom-events

I'm writing an angular app, and I'm using `addEventListener` for several events. My question is, when the route changes, are the event listeners still active? And if so do they need to be manually removed to prevent memory leaks?

I'm targeting modern browsers: Safari, Firefox, Chrome, IE >= 10

Comment: Why are you using `addEventListener` in an Angular app when it already has so many event methods available to it?

Comment: I don't really have an answer for that. I have a weird habit of trying to use vanilla js whenever its available. So to that end, does .on need to be unbound on DOM changes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using 'vanilla js' to bind events to the dom they will not be unbound, so you should manually do this. I see no reason why you would bind events like this when using angular though.

A nice post explaining everything:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/27016855/5223929