# What really needs to be cleaned up with the directive $destroy event?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

When I use angularjs, lately I have gotten into the habit of taking advantage of the directive $destroy event, usually I do something like

```
$scope.$on('$destroy', function() {
  $element = null;
  $attrs = null;
  outOfScopeVariable = null;
});
```

My questions are,

1. What's really necessary to do here?
2. How does this work with transcluded directives?
3. Best practices?

Comment: I do recommend to read up on this http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2706-always-trigger-the-destroy-event-before-removing-elements-in-angularjs-directives.htm

Comment: you may want to take a look at this too http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26983696/angularjs-does-destroy-remove-event-listeners