# Do we need to remove event listeners

Tags: angularjs, events, angularjs-scope, listener, dom-events

I am using the below event listener in my directive code in Angular JS to execute certain logic once that event is triggered:

```
element.on("change", function(e) {
//Logic goes here
}
```

I want to know whether do we need to manually destroy these listeners or will angular destroy their listeners. If we need to manually remove, could you help me how to remove these event listeners?

Comment: Check out this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26983696/angularjs-does-destroy-remove-event-listeners) for a great explanation.

Answer (score 0):

It will be removed automatically