# how to change the angularjs custom directive templateUrl dynamically with using scope

Tags: angularjs

This is my first question so I hope I can explain the situation
The angularJs documentation [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive) talks about having the directive templateUrl as a function to be returned dynamically. There is also a Plunkler live demo [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/?p=preview).

```
.directive('....', function() {
   return {
     templateUrl: function(elem, attr){
       return **.... scope.Somthing ...**;
     }
   };
 });
```

the function does not take a scope parameter and this is the main issue

The only way so far that i found is to set the TemplateUrl dynamically with relevance to the directive scope is this way

```
.directive('....', function() {
  return {
    link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
      scope.getTemplateUrl = function () {
        return **.... scope.Somthing ...**;
      };
    },
    template: '<ng-include src="getTemplateUrl()"/>'
  };
});
```

another solution is

```
.directive('....', function() {
  return {
    controller: function ($scope) {
      $scope.getTemplateUrl = function () {
        return **.... scope.Somthing ...**;
      };
    },
    template: '<ng-include src="getTemplateUrl()"/>'
  };
});
```

my first issue is that this looks like patch to the problem

my second issue is having to build html string in the directive.

Is there any other way to achive ?

Comment: I'd use a variable instead of a function call in the `ng-include`, but I think what you're doing is perfectly fine. If you're uncomfortable having HTML in the directive, you could always save that snippet to a file instead. This is way simpler than injecting `$compile` and dynamically compiling the template yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Lets split your problem for 2 problems :D

First problem is about storing template in js.

This problem can be solved using the $templateCache and injecting

```
<script id="myTemplate.html" type="text/ng-template"> <div> SOME MARKUP <div> </script>
```

[Here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/script) you can read more about this

Second problem is about dynamic templating. 
So there is 2 solutions (as far as i know :D) 
First solution you have already mentioned - using ng-include.

Second solution is to use [$compile](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile) to dynamicly compile html with angular directives.

First solution is little bit better, because in the second case you have to always remember about memory leak. Look here for more [info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26983696/angularjs-does-destroy-remove-event-listeners) and [here](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2706-always-trigger-the-destroy-event-before-removing-elements-in-angularjs-directives.htm)

Comment: thank for your answer it is very informative. So there is no other good way than the one i have in my quastion?.. I wish the angular team would let the template handle a function with a scope attribute

Comment: Angular team is working with angular 2.0 So I do not think that new features in Angular 1 will come soon.
If my answer helps you, please mark it as answer. Ty.