# $destroy event called after $state change (angular ui)

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, angular-ui

i m using ui router for state management. i have some directives that are behaving as listeners of some events

```
  app.directive('signer', ['Constant', "GlobalService", 
    function (constant, globalService) {
     return {
            restrict: "A",
            scope: {},
  link: function (scope, element) {
var workflowLoaded;
 workflowLoaded = scope.$on('event:workflowLoaded', function (data) {
                globalService.performAction();
            });

scope.$on('$destroy', function () {                
                if (workflowLoaded) workflowLoaded();               
            });
  }
      }
    }]);
```

**Scenario** : 
user navigating from one **view to other view**  that contains **Signer** directive which reloads the directive

**Issue**:
when item.html loads it register for event, but as $destory called after $statechangesuccess it de-register the event.

how to resolve the issue, any help will be appreciated

they have discussed it here but i cant find the solution 
https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/2485

Comment: The directive is destroyed when the view is changed along with its listeners. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: its was expected that directive destroy will be called before state change . but in reality its not happening .i m unregister events on destroy

Comment: That is redundant code. check this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27016855/2652883

Comment: That is not redundant code as next UI view holds same html and its required with newer values .  https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/2485