# Difference between delete and $destroy

Tags: javascript, angularjs, memory-leaks

I have been looking into memory leak management for angularjs and I have came across `$destroy` but in JavaScript there is already a `delete` keyword. Is there a difference between the two?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AngularJS - Does $destroy remove event listeners?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26983696/angularjs-does-destroy-remove-event-listeners)

Answer (score 1):

In  JavaScript delete operator removes a property from an object; if no more references to the same property are held, it is eventually released automatically.

```
var Employee = {
  firstname: "Mohammed",
  lastname: "Haddad"
}

console.log(Employee.firstname);
// expected output: "Mohammed"

delete Employee.firstname;

console.log(Employee.firstname);
// expected output: undefined
```

In angular , $scope.$destroy() is executed it will remove all listeners registered via $on on that $scope.

```
$scope.$on("$destroy", function() {
});
```